# Rails: "private method `require' called for #<Hash..." when creating a record manually (not through the form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a text file with data which I need to store in the database.

In a Rails controller action, I have something like this:

```
class ImportDataController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: :abc_client

  def abc_client
    ...simplified code:...
    ...loading data from a file...
    car = {}
    car[:attr1] = something
    car[:attr2] = something
    car[:attr3] = something
    ...and so on...

    ...now I try to save the record to the DB...
    @car = Cars::Crud::CreateService.new(car).create
  end
end
```

And I get this error:

```
private method `require' called for #<Hash:0x007fb2e2ef6040>
```

and the error points on this block of the code:

```
def car_params(params)
  params.require(:car).permit(:attr1, :attr2, ...)
```

I tried to also create a record "normally" via a Rails form and copied the hash from the console and tried to save it, like:

```
params = {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kXMd23s4msX2OzhUAX2CWqyphnpCPNorQOvoitatj8uBsQBgGYbTgfoR1wTTWlufo++esyb5m9ogBfSHbCrAPA==", "car"=>{"attr1"=>"6", ...

@car = Cars::Crud::CreateService.new(params).create
```

But it resulted in the same error message.

How do I figure it out?

Thank you

Comment: Where/how do you call `car_params`?

Comment: Note that `params.require` expects `params` to be an `ActionController::Parameters`. It does NOT work on a plain hash.

Comment: I do call `car_params`  from (Crud) services (Cars -> Crud -> CreateService -> here's the call of `car_params`). If I load data from a file and putting it to a hash, can I somehow convert this plain hash to `ActionController::Parameters`? Is there a way to simulate this behavior (or possibly work-around it)? Thank you

Comment: Just don't use require/permit. You can closely emulate it with fetch/slice.

Comment: I need to use it, because 90% of the application is using this structure. The rest 10% will use loading & saving data from the file to the DB.

Comment: "Is there a way to simulate this behavior (or possibly work-around it)" - yes. fetch/slice.

Answer (score 8):

It's tough to answer without knowing where `car_params` is defined, but I can tell you with certainty that the issue is that the `params` you are passing it is an ordinary Ruby `Hash` and not a Rails `ActionController::Parameters`, which is where `#require` is defined.

You can either not use strong parameters, and replace it with `fetch` and `slice`, like so:

```
params.fetch(:car).slice(:attr1, :attr2, ...)
```

Or if you really want to use strong parameters, you can wrap your Hash like so:

```
ActionController::Parameters.new(some_ruby_hash)
```

And then you can call `#require` and `#permit` on it.